How to make a custom cell/row menu clickable (3 dots at top right) in a List with NavigationLink
I am trying to show popover when user click on custom cell/row menu in List. But every time the cell get the action and navigating to inside the details screen. Here is my code snippet. Also attached screenshot for reference.
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ZStack {
                List {
                    Image("HeaderImage")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(height: 150)
                        .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
                    ForEach((0..<8), id: \.self) { index in
                            NavigationLink(destination: Text("screen1")) {
                                CustomCellView()
                            }
                            NavigationLink(destination: Text("screen2")) {
                                CustomCellView(imageName: "paintpalette")
                            }
                            NavigationLink(destination: Text("screen3")) {
                                CustomCellView(imageName: "slider.horizontal.3")
                            }
                    }
                }
                .listStyle(.plain)
                .navigationBarTitle("Users")                    
            }
        }
    }



Need the 3dot button action should come to main view to show the popover (and entire cell should not be clickable)
Is there any best way to hide the right chevron (without using .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 16, bottom: 0, trailing: -8)))

Thanks in advance.

You could probably resolve all the issues just by using a VStack (or LazyVStack) inside a ScrollView, instead of a List.

@BenzyNeez We may not get all the benefits with ScrollView. I have provided my answer below to achieve the code what I required.

Here is a my code snippet without using the NavigationLink for custom cell.
@State var viewModel: UserListViewModel
@State private var selectedUserId: UUID?
init(viewModel: UserListViewModel) {
    self.viewModel = viewModel
}

var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
        ZStack {
            List(viewModel.users ?? [], selection: $selectedUserId) {
                CellView(user: $0)
            }
            .navigationDestination(item: $selectedUserId, destination: { key in
                if let users = viewModel.users,
                   let index = users.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == key }) {
                    DetailView(user: users[index])
                }
                
            })
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Users"))
        }
    }
}

Also, I have  used

.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())

to get button action (3dot button action on each cell) to show cell menu options.
